# Angular extension might not work correctly because ngcc operation failed

Tags: angular, npm, angular-language-service

[image]

This is the error I am getting.

[image]

However `ng serve` is running without any issues.

[image]

I am also getting this is a problem but I have imported `ReactiveFormsModule` correctly and it is also working as expected in the website I am just getting this error randomly.

I tried deleting node_modules multiple times, I even deleted the npm cache folder in my Local but still getting this error after `npm i`. This is a new project I created with Angular 16.

```
{
  "name": "testProject",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "^16.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "^16.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "^16.1.1",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^16.0.1",
    "@ngrx/store": "^16.0.1",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^16.0.1",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.1.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^16.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.1.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.6.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.1.3"
  }
}
```

Any help and suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My issue was with Visual Studio Code.

My Angular version is `v16.1.1` but VS Code was somehow downloading Angular Language Service `v15.2.4`.

Reinstalled Visual Studio Code and it fixed the issue.

If you're having the same issue check if the Angular Language Service extension version and angular version are compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Sriharish's answer also helped me resolve this issue. I started running into this issue after updating to Angular 16 and I couldn't figure out why. Turns out it was because VSCode kept installing version 15 for the Angular Language Service extension. I uninstalled and re-installed VSCode and that fixed the issue. Thanks Sriharish!

Comment: Simon & @SriharishS does VS Code automatically remember all the previous settings, extensions, workspace config, git config, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing lock file and node_modules and reinstall everything, ngcc was removed in angular 16. Maybe update angular extension as well.

Comment: I tried that already, deleted package-lock.json and deleted node_modules folder multiple times and reinstalled again. Angular Extension also uninstalled and reinstalled multiple times. No change 